# How to compute how likely you are to choose option A

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

I am a mathematician and I am not an expert in statistics but I really would like to learn. I explain my problem.
There is an industry with several employes. Each of them can choose one between three possible options: A, B, C. I would like to understand which variables between sex, age, being a manager or not influences the choice.

Once that I determined which variables are relevant in the choice I would like to constract a kind of statistical indicator that could tell me which is the probability that the employe Alex (which is a man, 30 years old, not a manager) chooses the option A.

Suppose I have the data of a big number of employes and I know which choice they did. There is a way to constract such probability?

If someone can suggest me a book that explains this kind of argument I would be really greatful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=discrete+rational+choice+model&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart will show you one family of approaches.

Comment: Ok! I will give a look! Thanks